# print document display with web browser

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've created print document that preview set in a image viewer in my desktop application & I am happy for this performance.

Now I want to display created document with web browser (Mozila/Chrome/IE). 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the document is in PDF format then you could set `Content-Disposition` HTTP header to `inline`. It will work pretty much in every modern browser.